# About the raised negative sign in some basic textbooks

Tags: notation, education

In a math document recently (a UK A level test paper from the EdExcel board), I noticed that the negative/minus sign was raised and aligned to the top of the number. I'm interested to know whether this is a local or regional habit, how common or widespread it is, and whether it's considered a good idea.

(The only anecdote I have about this habit is that a student queried the sign as if it were some kind of printing error...:)

#### Examples

> $A$ and $B$ are points with coordinates $(5,2)$ and $(\vphantom 1^- 1, 4)$ respectively.

and

> Given that $(x+2)$ and $(x-3)$ are factors of $f(x)$, show that $a=3$ and $b=\vphantom 1^- 10$.

(These are not from the same question.)

Comment: Even though it is on the left, I think it is not a good practice given a similar thing is used with limits to show approaching from the left or right (although there the  $\pm$ is shown on the top-right side of the number). I see no good reason to do it this way and cannot say I have ever seen this before.

Comment: This is, as far as I am aware, not a UK convention (or even an EdExcel exam convention) and is most likely a printing error. It is possible that since I was at school, they have decided to distinguish between minus signs as operations and those indicating negative numbers, because this sounds like exactly the kind of insane thing that schools are forced to do all the time.

Comment: Never seen this before, what a stupid idea.

Comment: Decidedly an ungood idea. Doubleplusungood.

Comment: Oh God ye should see some of the rubbish that is passing for maths in the primary school sector here. They don't realise that $2-3=2+(-3)$ and that $-3$ has the property that $3+(-3)=0$.

Comment: The programming language APL uses this notation.  That's maybe where they got it from, although I think I remember seeing it in primary school in England in the 1970's.  It is to distinguish the unitary operation "minus" from the binary operation "subtract."

Comment: TI calculators also use this notation, with separate buttons for unary and binary minus.